# "Logical identity" as defined in Munkres

Tags: logic, terminology

The following passage, on a concept which should be rather straightforward, is directly out of Munkres's Topology:

> The equality symbol $=$ is used throughout this book to mean *logical identity.* Thus, when we write $a = b$, we mean that "$a$" or "$b$" are symbols for the same object.

I haven't ever heard of the term "logical identity." The only other use of it I have been able to find is in reference to propositions $p$ and $q$, in the context of writing $p \iff q$. It makes sense to say that if $a = b$, then we have $a \iff b$ in the sense that if something is equal to $a$, it is also equal to $b$. Is this what Munkres is getting at? Is there a clearer way of thinking about this?

Comment: I think he is just saying that $a = b$ means that $a$ *is* $b$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$a=b$ is certainly *not* the same as $a \Leftrightarrow b$

$a =b$ is about the identity of *objects*.

$a \Leftrightarrow b$ is about the *logical equivalance* of *claims*.

Note that $a=b$ is a claim, but $a$ and $b$ need not be claims themselves; they can be any object. And even if they happen to be claims then we mean to say that they are the exact same claim, not merely logically equivalent claims. So, for example, if $a$ refers to the claim $P$ and $b$ also refers to the claim $P$, then we have $a=b$, but with $a$ being $P$ and $b$ being $\neg \neg P$, we do not have $a=b$, but we do have $a \Leftrightarrow b$

But again, $a$ and $b$ need not refer to claims at all, and often when used in logic expressions they do not. They could, for example, refer to numbers, and then $a=b$ makes the claim that $a$ and $b$ are the same number. And, in that case, $a \Leftrightarrow b$ makes no sense at all: logical equivalence does not apply to numbers.

The author probably uses the term *logical identity* to stress the fact that the = is a *logical* symbol (a symbol of the language of logic) and thus has a fixed interpretation ... namely the interpretation of identity.